# ReportLab embed video in pdf

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

Is it possible to embed videos into a pdf document with Reportlab? Or any other python library for that matter? It seems like there is software that does it but I'm really looking for a library that can do it and haven't found any.

Comment: Have you ever seen a normal PDF with a video inside? As far as I know, this isn't possible...

Comment: It seems that the pdf format supports it, but with no known implementation in Reportlab, yet. https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/rich-media.html